# Shift+Enter error at running Selection/Line in python terminal using

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After upgrading to VS code version 1.81.0 VS code seem to be activating Python after sending the the code, using Shift+Enter, sending 1+1

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3324]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\fail\gitprojects\proj_x>activate

(base) C:\Users\fail\gitprojects\proj_x>conda activate env_proj_x

(env_proj_x) C:\Users\fail\gitprojects\proj_x>1+1
'1+1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(env_proj_x) C:\Users\fail\gitprojects\proj_x>C:/Users/fail/.conda/envs/env_proj_x/python.exe
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

This time sending the code, using Shift+Enter, everything works as it should, as Python is activated.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The latest version is 1.82.0, you can continue to update your vscode.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT unfortunately not an option at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like an error that should be reported in github:

```
Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Trying to `Shift+Enter` a `print("Hello")` the first time it launches the python shell

```
Daviid ~
 13:10:02 λ & C:/Users/Daviid/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>>
```

The next time I press `Shift+Enter` it sends the selected text to the python shell.

However if I do `exit()` now I see `print("hello")` in the terminal:

```
Daviid ~
 13:14:19 λ print("Hello")
No se puede inicializar el dispositivo PRN
```

This can be "fixed" by setting

```json
"jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true
```

I quote "fixed" because it's not the exactly the same as this happening in a single `Shift+Enter`

```
Daviid ~
 13:10:02 λ & C:/Users/Daviid/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>>
```

I say to report the error in github but it might just be how it's always been and need to be a feature suggestion.

Edit:

Here's how the jupyter setting enabled looks like:
[image]

Comment: I am not looking to send it to an interactive Jupyter window, but simply sent to the terminal. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then, you probably want to open an issue in vdcode's github